# Efficient algorithm to find the n-th digit in the string 112123123412345

Tags: algorithm

What is an efficient algorithm for finding the *digit* in nth position in the following string

```
112123123412345123456 ... 123456789101112 ...
```

Storing the entire string in memory is not feasible for very large n, so I am looking for an algorithm that can find the nth digit in the above string which works if n is very large (i.e. an alternative to just generating the first n digits of the string).

Comment: You don't need an algorithm for accessing a character of a string. What language are you using?

Comment: @Harald I suspect the OP wants a formula for finding the digit in the nth position, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If n is very large say 10^10 or so it is infeasible to store the entire string in memory, I am asking of an algorithm to workaround this. Sorry for the confusion, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: First, you need to find the largest integer ``p`` such that p(p+1)/2<n. Then, it should be easy since ``n`` is in the ``p+1``-th set...

Comment: @xiawi I stress the *digit* in the nth position. E.g. once you get further along in the string you get numbers with two or more digits (10,..., 100,.. etc). So there is no guarantee that n is in the p+1th set.

Comment: try using sliding window algorithm preferably with an queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several levels here: the digit is part of a number x, the number x is part of a sequence 1,2,3...x...y and that sequence is part of a block of sequences that lead up to numbers like y that have z digits. We'll tackle these levels one by one.

There are 9 numbers with 1 digit:

```
first: 1 (sequence length: 1 * 1)  
last: 9 (sequence length: 9 * 1)  
average sequence length: (1 + 9) / 2 = 5  
1-digit block length: 9 * 5 = 45
```

There are 90 numbers with 2 digits:

```
first: 10 (sequence length: 9 * 1 + 1 * 2)  
last: 99 (sequence length: 9 * 1 + 90 * 2)  
average sequence length: 9 + (2 + 180) / 2 = 100  
2-digit block length: 90 * 100 = 9000
```

There are 900 numbers with 3 digits:

```
first: 100 (sequence length: 9 * 1 + 90 * 2 + 1 * 3)  
last: 999 (sequence length: 9 * 1 + 90 * 2 + 900 * 3)  
average sequence length: 9 + 180 + (3 + 2,700) / 2 = 1,540.5  
3-digit block length: 900 * 1,540.5 = 1,386,450
```

If you continue to calculate these values, you'll find which block (of sequences up to how many digits) the digit you're looking for is in, and you'll know the start and end point of this block.

Say you want the millionth digit. You find that it's in the 3-digit block, and that this block is located in the total sequence at:

```
start of 3-digit block: 45 + 9,000 + = 9,045  
start of 4-digit block: 45 + 9,000 + 1,386,450 = 1,395,495
```

So in this block we're looking for digit number:

```
1,000,000 - 9,045 = 990,955
```

Now you can use e.g. a binary search to find which sequence the 990,955th digit is in; you start with the 3-digit number halfway in the 3-digit block:

```
first: 100 (sequence length: 9 + 180 + 1 * 3)  
number: 550 (sequence length: 9 + 180 + 550 * 3)  
average sequence length: 9 + 180 + (3 + 1650) / 2 = 1,015.5  
total sequence length: 550 * 1,015.5 = 558,525
```

Which is too small; so we try 550 * 3/4 = 825, see if that is too small or large, and go up or down in increasingly smaller steps until we know which sequence the 990,995th digit is in.

Say it's in the sequence for the number n; then we calculate the total length of all 3-digit sequences up to n-1, and this will give us the location of the digit we're looking for in the sequence for the number n. Then we can use the numbers 9*1, 90*2, 900*3 ... to find which number the digit is in, and then what the digit is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a series of sequences each increasing by a single number.

If you have "x" of them, then the sequences up to that point occupy `x * (x + 1) / 2` character positions.  Or, another way of saying this is that the "x"s sequence starts at `x * (x - 1) / 2` (assuming zero-based indexing).  These are called triangular numbers.

So, all you need to do is to find the "x" value where the cumulative amount is closest to a given "n".  Here are three ways:

- Search for a closed from solution.  This exists, but the formula is rather complicated.  ([Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227155102/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56926.html) is one reference for the sum of triangular numbers.)
- Pre-calculate a table in memory with values up to, say, 1,000,000.  that will get you to 10^10 sizes.
- Use a "binary" search and the formula.  So, generate the sequence of values for 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on and then do a binary search to find the exact sequence.

Once you know the sequence where the value lies, determining the value is simply a matter of arithmetic.

Comment: Why does it work? The numbers aren't all one character, that seems like it would break that formula

Comment: I don't see your second paragraph. E.g. take x=12. Then you have 1, 12, 123, ...., 123456789101112. Using your formula would give (12*13)/2=78 character positions when in reality there are more. This is due to the fact that some numbers take multiple digits (e.g. if the number is bigger than 10).

Comment: @user3186512 . . . Interesting.  I was thinking of it as an array of values, even though you do explicitly describe it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

We have three types of structures that we would like to be able to search on, (1) the sequence of concatenating `d`-digit numbers, for example, single digit:

```
123456...
```

or 3-digit:

```
100101102103
```

(2) the rows in a section,
where each section builds on the previous section added to a prefix. For example, section 1:

```
1
12
123
...
```

or section 3:

```
1234...10111213...100
1234...10111213...100102
1234...10111213...100102103
<----- prefix ----->
```

and (3) the full sections, although the latter we can just enumerate since they grow exponentially and help build our section prefixes. For (1), we can use simple division if we know the digit count; for (2), we can binary search.

Here's Python code that also answers the big ones:

```py
def getGreatest(n, d, prefix):
  rows = 9 * 10**(d - 1)
  triangle = rows * (d + rows * d) // 2
  l = 0
  r = triangle
 
  while l < r:
    mid = l + ((r - l) >> 1)
    triangle = mid * prefix + mid * (d + mid * d) // 2
    prevTriangle = (mid-1) * prefix + (mid-1) * (d + (mid-1) * d) // 2
    nextTriangle = (mid+1) * prefix + (mid+1) * (d + (mid+1) * d) // 2
 
    if triangle >= n:
      if prevTriangle < n:
        return prevTriangle
      else:
        r = mid - 1
    else:
      if nextTriangle >= n:
        return triangle
      else:
        l = mid
 
  return l * prefix + l * (d + l * d) // 2
 
def solve(n):
  debug = 1
  d = 0
  p = 0.1
  prefixes = [0]
  sections = [0]
 
  while sections[d] < n:
    d += 1
    p *= 10
    rows = int(9 * p)
    triangle = rows * (d + rows * d) // 2
    section = rows * prefixes[d-1] + triangle
    sections.append(sections[d-1] + section)
    prefixes.append(prefixes[d-1] + rows * d)
 
  section = sections[d - 1]
 
  if debug:
    print("section: %s" % section)
 
  n = n - section
  rows = getGreatest(n, d, prefixes[d - 1])
 
  if debug:
    print("rows: %s" % rows)
 
  n = n - rows
 
  d = 1
 
  while prefixes[d] < n:
    d += 1;
 
  if prefixes[d] == n:
    return 9;
 
  prefix = prefixes[d - 1]
 
  if debug:
    print("prefix: %s" % prefix)
 
  n -= prefix
 
  if debug:
    print((n, d, prefixes, sections))
 
  countDDigitNums = n // d
  remainder = n % d
 
  prev = 10**(d - 1) - 1
  num = prev + countDDigitNums
 
  if debug:
    print("num: %s" % num)
 
  if remainder:
    return int(str(num + 1)[remainder - 1])
  else:
    s = str(num);
    return int(s[len(s) - 1])
 
ns = [
  1, # 1
  2, # 1
  3, # 2
  100, # 1
  2100, # 2
  31000, # 2
  999999999999999999, # 4
  1000000000000000000, # 1
  999999999999999993, # 7
]
 
for n in ns:
  print(n)
  print(solve(n))
  print('')
```